# How to fetch all Conversations a User belongs to?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I would like to fetch every Conversation a specific User belongs to. Is this possible server side? It seems like the only option is to iterate through every Conversation and filter.

Am I expected to track every Conversation a User belongs to in my own database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, this is not available in conversations but conversations is adopting more functionality from Programmable Chat, so this functionality may appear in Conversations at some point in the future.

Comment: are we already at that time in the future?